# Large CSV file download in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, http, csv, large-files

I need to export a really large csv file(~100MB). On the internet I found a similar code and implemented it for my case:

```
public class CSVExporter
{
    public static void WriteToCSV(List<Person> personList)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=PersonList.csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        WriteColumnName();
        foreach (Person person in personList)
        {
            WriteUserInfo(person);
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    private static void WriteUserInfo(Person person)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        AddComma(person.Name, stringBuilder);
        AddComma(person.Family, stringBuilder);
        AddComma(person.Age.ToString(), stringBuilder);
        AddComma(string.Format("{0:C2}", person.Salary), stringBuilder);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private static void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(value.Replace(',', ' '));
        stringBuilder.Append(", ");
    }

    private static void WriteColumnName()
    {
        string columnNames = "Name, Family, Age, Salary";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

The problem is I want to start the download before(!) the whole CSV is constructed. Why is not it working like I suppose it too and what must I change?

Comment: Two quick comments: pass in an IEnumerable<Person> and avoid pre-populating the list (for 100MB output it most likely has a lot of entries), and flush the response output every 1000 lines or so.

Comment: @Morten Mertner, yes, thank you, I already do that, this was a found sample I based the code on

Comment: I'm curious as to where you put this in your MVC framework?  Did you just call the WriteToCSV() method from the action?

Comment: If you solved this, can you provide the final code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably force the response to be flushed to the client by using

```
Response.Flush();
```

after each record is appended to the stream. Please refer to this article for more details:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406

Comment: Probably a little more efficient to flush after every 50 or 100 records or so, not every single one.